# Is localforage working with nativescript preview app on IOS?

Tags: nativescript

while using localforage for storing data for an app, I got an error while initializing the localforage.

```
Error: No available storage method found.
```

I tried to setup it with

```
localforage.INDEXEDDB
localforage.WEBSQL
localforage.LOCALSTORAGE
```

but the bug stays.
I use the nativescript preview app on an iphone.
May the preview app have the rights to store data on an iphone?

Regards Juergen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

preview only works with certain pre-set packages as it is not able to build.
try connecting a device to your machine and using the run command

### <= NativeScript 6

tns run ios

tns run android

### NativeScript 7

ns run ios

ns run android